# ifelse() in case of missing values in some cases but not all /R

Tags: r

I have the two events `t$recurrence` and `t$dead` which each have corresponding event times called `t$rfs` and `t$os`, respectively.

I want to prepare the dataset for a competing risk analysis. Therefore, I have created `t$event.time`.

However, I have `667 cases in t$recurrence` and correspondingly `667 event times in t$rfs`. For the same 667 cases, I have the `t$dead==0 or 1` in 517 cases (equal to 150 missing `t$dead==0 or 1`). Similarly, I have 517 survival times in `t$os`.

Taken this into account, I need to define `t$event.time` as:

**IF**

`t$dead==0 & t$recurrence==1` then `t$event.time==t$rfs` AND

`t$dead==1 & t$recurrence==1` then `t$event.time==t$rfs` AND

**ELSE**

`t$dead==0 & t$recurrence==0` then `t$event.time==t$os` AND

`t$dead==1 & t$recurrence==0` then `t$event.time==t$os`

**BUT ALSO**

`t$dead is NA` then `t$event.time==t$rfs`

I tried different attempts using the ifelse()-argument, but that did not solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you've shown in your logic table, the following should work:

```
ifelse(is.na(t$dead) | t$recurrence == 1, t$rfs, t$os)
```